# iterate through certain number of foreign key objects

Tags: python, django, django-templates, foreign-keys

I have a model `Comments` with a foreign key to another model `BaseRecipe`. I have a DetailView calling the `BaseRecipe`. I am doing the following to display all the comments for `BaseRecipe`:

```
    {% for comment in object.comment_link.all %}

    <h5>Comment {{ forloop.counter }}</h5>
    <p>{{ comment.comment_text }}</p>
    <p>{{ comment.pub_date |date }}</p>

{%endfor %}
```

This works great.But, I want to change this so that it only shows the last x number of comments. I have tried:

```
{% for comment in object.comment_link.all{[:5] %}
```

&

```
{% for comment[:5] in object.comment_link.all %}
```

I tried some different logic, but it would not let me set initial values for loops (not sure if you can do that in templates). Im thinking maybe i should create a  variable in the view that is a list of the last x numbers of comments? It seems like there should be some easy operator to do this that i have not stumbled across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in templates. As you do not only want 5 comments but you also want to order them (latest 5). You can add a method in your `BaseRecipe` model class to get recent comments.

```
class BaseRecipe(models.Model):
    def get_recent_comments(self, n=5):
        return self.comment_link.all().order_by('-id')[:n]
```

Then call this method in your template

```
{% for comment in object.get_recent_comments %}
```

Comment: this is perfect, I was trying to do this earlier but failed to use a def and return something.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice`

```
{% for comment in object.comment_link.all|slice:":10" %}
```